# Count total number of workers based on today's date updating automatically every day

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm a bit stumped on how to create a formula that can count the total number of workers today and update automatically every day.

Looking at the image below, I want to create a formula that will look at **Row 10**, determine today's date and look at **Row 39** to determine how many workers I had for that day.

For example, if I look at today's date on the image Cell `AZ10` and then scroll down and look at total workers for the day Cell `AZ39` it should be `6`. When the next day comes, `2018-03-05`, I would like the cell to automatically update to the number of workers for that day, which would be `7`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

[image: Workers spreadsheet]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`HLOOKUP` function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/hlookup-function-a3034eec-b719-4ba3-bb65-e1ad662ed95f) (Horizontal Lookup) to obtain the value you require.

For example, assuming that your data occupies the range from `AZ10` to `BZ39`, the following formula will obtain the number of workers present today:

```
=HLOOKUP(TODAY(),AZ10:BZ39,30,FALSE)
```

Here the arguments are as follows:

- `TODAY()` returns today's date
- `AZ10:BZ39` is the range of cells whose first row contains the lookup value and which also contains a row whose value is to be returned.
- `30` is the number of row whose value is to be returned (relative to the supplied range).
- `FALSE` means there must be an exact match between the cell value in the first row of the supplied range and the supplied lookup value.

The `HLOOKUP` function is looking along row `AZ` for a value which *exactly matches* (because of the `FALSE` parameter) today's date (as returned by `TODAY()`). If such a value is found, the function will then return the value found in row 30 of the range - that is, in row 39 of your worksheet.

Comment: Hi Lee Mac, that was perfect! Thank you for explaining each part of the formula. That really helped me to understand :)